# Identify particular building:part belongs to which building in OSM

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api, identify, building

Since there is different osm_ids for building:part and its respective building. Lets say https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/182827369 is the main building and https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/530727727 this is the URL of building:part. Is it possible programmatically to understand that this building:part belongs to this building? Or there is any API available?

Comment: Iterate polygons.  If building = yes, select by location any polygon touching that building.  Iterate selection, if building_part = yes then that part might belong to the adjacent building.  Some geometries may be ambiguous if the part touches more that one building.

Comment: can you provide code for it?It will be very helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [osm api for input building\_name and output all its building:part in osm?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/441260/osm-api-for-input-building-name-and-output-all-its-buildingpart-in-osm)

Comment: it has not got any answer