# API for input building_name and output all its building:part in OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo, building

Is there an API available in which we can send a building name and it would return all buildings:part if they exist in OpenStreetMap?

Comment: Did you already take a look at Overpass API?

Comment: Duplicate: [Identify particular building:part belongs to which building in OSM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/441205/identify-particular-buildingpart-belongs-to-which-building-in-osm)

Comment: yes i am using overpass api, but i am not able to figure out what is the common link between building:part and building, its osm id is different, nothing common tag i am able to understand

Comment: This part has already been answered in your other question.

Comment: Bring your data into ArcGIS or QGIS.  Find tutorials on iterating data, and making select by location operations with one of those software packages.  Come back with GIS-Stack-Exchange compliant (focused and specific) questions about where and when you get stuck.